# asus zenbook and ubuntu 20.04

Tags: asus, 20.04

I am considering upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 on my Asus Zenbook UX433FA. I know I had issues initially with 18.04, some with the sound and also issue where start up froze on black/purple screen. Anyone tried upgrading yet with the same hardware as what I have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: That does, thank you @Pilot6

Answer (score 0):

The stuck was maybe due to the nvidia graphics card.
if you installed nvidia propiertary driver.i think there will be no chance of getting stuck in bootmenu , also please remove nouveau.modeset=0 from grub entry if you have already installed nvidia drivers .

The one i am using has i5-9th gen and 1050 4GB graphics card
There is no issue at all